# Strange behavior with Boolean Difference

Tags: modeling

I'm getting strange behavior with Boolean Difference as per the attached file.

I'm trying to cut a notch into the U-shaped object using either of the two shapes on the right.

[image]

With the more complex shape, I can't get a notch at all.

With the simpler shape, I can get a notch, but not when it's exactly flush with the U-shaped object (I want to do it when the cutting shape is flush).

Please see the following file: [image]

Any ideas? Many thanks!

Comment: As @moonbots mentions sometimes the boolean modifier encounters problems, when surfaces overlap exactly (inside and outside are not well defined anymore). However you can still do an exact cut, as long as you know which offset you use. So if you extrude the faces of the cutting shape that are supposed to be flush by e.g. 0.1 units you can then place it by making it flush first and then later translating it by that value of 0.1 units. So the positioning will still be as exact as you get, while the boolean will work normally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How is your notch supposed to be? From what I experience:

- You need to lower down your small cube a bit, otherwise its bottom face will overlap the U bottom face and it's a problem for the *Boolean* modifier. Now it works well.

[image]

- For the second shape, it looks like it works correctly, what problem have you encountered?

[image]